# Hide the div section using custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I have created a custom directive to show the error messages in the page. My directive is

```
     app.directive('errorsection', function () {
     return {
       restrict: 'EA',
       scope: {
        errors: '=errors'
     },
     templateUrl: '..../shared/error-section.html'
     };
      });
```

error-section.html

```
   <div ng-show="errors.length>0" class="error">
    <div id="{{error.Id}}" ng-class="{'error':error.Type=='Error','alert-info alert-dismissible cssDataTargetDismiss-{{error.Id}} fade in':error.Type=='Info'}"
     ng-repeat="error in errors track by $index">
    <button ng-if="error.Type=='Info'" type="button" class="close" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".cssDataTargetDismiss-{{alert.Id}}">×</button>
    <p><strong ng-bind-html="error.TypeDescription"></strong><span ng-bind-html="error.Message"></span></p>
</div>
```

I have used this directive in one of my partial page to show the error messages

```
    <div error-section errors="errorList"></div>
```

this errorList contains 2 messages . if i click the button, message is collapsed. I want to hide the div if all the error messages collapsed..
error messages is showing in view like below format,

```
      ______________
     |error1       x|
     |error2       x|
      _______________
```

can anyone help how to hide the div?

Comment: Please take the time to look at the preview of your question befor ehitting send, especially spending attention to how your code looks in the question. unformatted code is really hard to read and makes people a lot less likely to help you.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<div ng-show="errors.length>0 && message !== 0">
    <div id="{{error.Id}}" ng-class="{'error':error.Type=='Error','alert-info alert-dismissible cssDataTargetDismiss-{{error.Id}} fade in':error.Type=='Info'}"
       ng-repeat="error in errors track by $index">
      <button ng-click="message -= 1" ng-if="error.Type=='Info'" type="button" class="close" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".cssDataTargetDismiss-{{alert.Id}}">×</button>
       <p><strong ng-bind-html="error.TypeDescription"></strong><span ng-bind-html="error.Message"></span></p>
```

and in your directive controller take the length of the messages and give it to $scope.message.

Comment: in directive what change i haveto made

Answer (score 0):

Change your directive to use replace instead:

```
app.directive('errorsection', function () {
    return {
        restrict : 'EA',
        scope : {
            errors : '=errors'
        },
        replace: true, //tell it to replace
        templateUrl : '..../shared/error-section.html'
    };
});
```

This will make it so that

```
<div error-section errors="errorList"></div>
```

And

```
<div ng-show="errors.length>0" class="error">
```

Are the same div like this:

```
<div error-section errors="errorList error" ng-show="errors.length>0">
    ...
</div>
```

As opposed to:

```
<div error-section errors="errorList">
    <div ng-show="errors.length>0" class="error">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```